# Html color code with double double quotes

Tags: colors

I am trying to solve a puzzle. I think the solution involves working out why in html if a colour code has double double inverted commas it will display the wrong colour. Eg ...

```
<font face color="“#b80707”" size>
```

This is the wrong colour. It is green but the hex key is red?

Is there a colour that will display correctly with this syntax? If so what would it be?

Comment: That's not a valid colour code. 

Do not use this syntax. There may be a "valid" colour code using this, but the behaviour is undefined and it is ultimately up to the browser what it does with incorrect values. Is there a real-world use case here?

Comment: Just a note that "undefined behavior" includes everything from "it seems to work perfectly every time", to "it works differently in different browsers", and "The computer grew legs, walked across the room, kicked my dog, then exploded.".

Comment: Here's a link to the puzzle where it appears..http://coord.info/GC5WRN5  it may be a coding error, or it may have been done deliberately and represent  the puzzle.